# contour integral of gradient

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

I have troubles with solving this integral, the only thing I know is that

$VI\dfrac{L}{\mu}\oint_{ch}\phi\nabla_t\phi\cdot \mathbf{\nu}\,\,dl$

= V*I * $\frac{L}{\mu}* \frac{C}{\epsilon}$, which means that the integral part must be equal to $\frac{C}{\epsilon}$. Additional to this, it is known that $\frac{C}{\epsilon}=\oint_{ch}-\nu\nabla_t\phi\cdot \,dl$

My question is how to get from the first integral to the second, while it is known that $\phi(Q) = 1 $ and $\phi(P) = 0 $ where P and Q are points on the contour

Comment: What is $c,\epsilon$ ?some more context would help

Comment: C is capacitance and e is epsilon (permittivity of free space).